# Delete session cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies

Why is it that when I call:

```
<?php

setcookie("PHPSESSID", "", time() - 3600);

?>
```

on a session cookie it doesn't get deleted but if I were to call it on another cookie it does get destroyed?

This works perfectly fine:

```
<?php

setcookie("tom", "tom", time() - 3600);

?>
```

but the above example with the session cookie doesn't.

I have tried this on google chrome and firefox and still get the same result when looking at the header files.

This is the output for session cookies:

```
Array
(
    [_GET] => Array
        (
        )

    [_POST] => Array
        (
        )

    [_COOKIE] => Array
        (
            [PHPSESSID] => v61njiklq3kd5koc6i8i7otab7
        )

    [_FILES] => Array
        (
        )

    [GLOBALS] => Array
 *RECURSION*
)
```

Comment: When do you check for the cookie in your dump? During the same request where you delete the cookie, or one request later? And did your code pass another `session_start()` then?

Comment: I deleted the line 'session_start()' and substituted it with the setcookie() one, then realoaded several times but cookie is still there. This is the only page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setcookie( session_name(), "", time()-3600, '/');
```

Works! The missing part to remove the session cookie was the last argument to the function 'setcookie()' as in '/'.

Answer (score 0):

It's because, when you call your script to delete the cookie, the session handler actually updates the session cookie to be still "online". You'll have to destroy the session, not just (trying) to delete the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be destroying the session like that anyway, you should instead be using the native function `session_destroy()` which destroys the session.

Normally that PHPSESSID cookie will just regenerate the next time session_start() is called anyway, which is probably why it appeared that you weren't deleting the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

To delete "PHPSESSID" cookie created by session_start() set it empty.

```
setcookie( "PHPSESSID", "", time()-3600, '/');
```